# FullCalendar returns Error when using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I search almost all of the related Error here in regarding Fullcalendar.

I have this JQuery, this is from this documentation https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "api/test.php",
     success: function(doc) {
      var events = [];
      $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
           events.push({
            title: $(this).attr('title'),
            start: $(this).attr('start') // will be parsed
           });

          });

          callback(events);
         }
    });
  }
});
```

But whenever I try run this code, it doesn't return anything in my calendar and it has this error in the console

```
VM8547 jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized 
expression:
 {
    "event": [
        {
            "title": "test 1",
            "start": "2015-10-20",
            "end": "2015-10-20"
        },
        {
            "title": "test 2",
            "start": "2016-04-18",
            "end": "2016-04-18"
        },
        {
            "title": "test 3",
            "start": "2017-07-22",
            "end": "2017-07-22"
        },
        {
            "title": "test 4",
            "start": "0000-00-00",
            "end": "0000-00-00"
        },
        {
            "title": "test 5",
            "start": "2015-08-26",
            "end": "2015-08-26"
        },
        {
            "title": "test 6",
            "start": "0000-00-00",
            "end": "0000-00-00"
        },
        {
            "title": "test 7",
            "start": "2018-01-10",
            "end": "2018-01-10"
        },
        {
            "title": "8",
            "start": "2018-07-09",
            "end": "2018-07-09"
        },
        {
            "title": "test 9",
            "start": "2018-05-28",
            "end": "2018-05-28"
        },
        {
            "title": "test 10",
            "start": "2016-03-10",
            "end": "2016-03-10"
        }
    ]
}
    at Function.fa.error (VM8547 jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at fa.tokenize (VM8547 jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at fa.select (VM8547 jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at Function.fa [as find] (VM8547 jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.find (VM8547 jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at new n.fn.init (VM8547 jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at n (VM8547 jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at Object.success (?page=test-kim:1882)
    at i (VM8547 jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (VM8547 jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
```

I cant find the issue here. I tried reading almost all of the fix I could find but nothing works.

Comment: How do you define `callback` ?

Comment: @cid im sorry but what do you mean how do i define? thats the most of my code. Im just new here.

Comment: unless your endpoint returns XML in a specific structure (as per the one in the example you've copied from verbatim without seemingly considering what the code is actually doing) then inevitably it will fail to process the response correctly. If, as it appears, your server returns JSON which is already in a format fullCalendar recognises, then you don't need to do any client-side-processing of the kind shown in the documentation. (P.S. I realise from your answer below that you've found a solution, but it wasn't clear from your answer whether you realised _why_ your change worked.)

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I fixed it by not using an ajax just in case someone needs it.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   eventSources: [
            {
                url: 'api/test.php'
            }
        ]
});
```